# Can not list all information in my attribute

Tags: sql, select, operator-keyword

I tried Write the SQL code to list all attributes information for job code of 501.

```
SELECT JOB_CODE
WHERE JOB_CODE = '501'
FROM EMP_1;
```

I keep get the error. It said

```
missing operator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is totally wrong:

It would be:

```
SELECT JOB_CODE
FROM EMP_1
WHERE JOB_CODE = '501';
```